# Z-index value ignored when using perspective

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I'm trying to zoom on a div once it's clicked. The problem I'm facing is that even though I update the z-index with jquery and it gets updated, it takes no effect on the div and other divs still stay on top, here's an example: http://coldtask.com/

If you click on any date, the box zooms in and expands, but other divs still stay on top, even though their z-index is 1 and the active div's z-index is 10. Thanks

Comment: So your trying to make it so when you click on a `div` it zooms and changes from `z-index: 1` to `z-index: 10`? And do you want it to toggle?

Comment: yes. It's already switching the z-index, but it has no effect, as you can see other 'minimized' dates are on top of 'expanded' div

Comment: There are three js sources, can you send me a link with the one that does the effect or copy the code to the post?

Comment: sure, I will create a jsfiddle, one sec, thanks!

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/81u71gpo/ whenever I click on the first cube, it's z-index gets set to 10, but it still is behind the second cube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set position relative for the z-index to work

```
.day-wrap
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    margin: 3px;
    position: relative;
    float:                          left;
    width:                          65px;
    height:                         50px;
    z-index:1;

    transform: perspective(100px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81u71gpo/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I did the following experiment:

```
<div id="blue" class="day-wrap" data-date="2015-03-22">
  <div class="day-class-outside">
    <div class="day-class"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- </div> -->

<div id="red" class="day-wrap" data-date="2015-03-22">
  <div class="day-class-outside">
    <div class="day-class"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#red, #red div, #red div div {
    background-color: green;
}

#blue, #blue div, #blue div div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

It worked perfectly fine. everything was perfect, although, of course, you did forgot to make `.day-wrap: relative`.

In other words, there was no problem with your original code.